# Kann eine Wohnung laut sein?

Tags: word-usage

Leute
In meinem Kursbuch steht das Folgende: "Leider ist die Wohnung sehr laut und sie hat keinen Balkon".
Wie kann eine Wohnung laut sein? Ich kann sagen, die Nachbarn sind laut, aber ein Gebäude?
Ich glaube, die Formulierung des Satzes ist sinnlos oder vielleicht ein bisschen komisch.
Was glaubt ihr? Ist das Hochdeutsch? :D

Answer (score 11):

Verständlich ist es auf jeden Fall. Ich würde auch sagen, dass es standardsprachlich ist: Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/laut_vernehmbar_droehnend) verzeichnet die Bedeutung *geräuschvoll, lärmerfüllt* mit dem Beispiel *eine laute Gegend, Straße*. Auch in diesen Fällen wird der Lärm durch Dritte verursacht.

Es gibt zugegebenermaßen einen Unterschied zwischen einer *lauten Straße* und einer *lauten Wohnung*: Bei ersterer geht der Lärm von ihr selbst aus, bei letzterer dringt der Lärm in sie ein. Meines Erachtens ist dies jedoch unerheblich, wenn man – wie der Duden – *lärmerfüllt* als Synonym betrachtet.

Das Gegenteil scheint mir dann allerdings nicht *leise*, sondern *ruhig* zu sein (*eine ruhige Wohnung, eine ruhige Straße*). Trotzdem könnte ich mir hier auch *leise* in der Bedeutung *nicht laut* vorstellen: *eine leise Straße, eine leise Wohnung*.

Comment: [Metonymie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymie).

Comment: Vielleicht ist "sinnlos" nicht das richtige Wort, aber es ist komisch für mich :D. Daran habe ich nicht gedacht. Es gibt auch einen Unterschied zwischen "die Wohnung ist laut" und "die Wohnung liegt laut", oder? Kann man das Letztere sagen? Im selben Kursbuch (Themen Aktuell) habe ich gesehen, das Haus liegt günstig.

Comment: *Günstig* bedeutet nicht nur *billig*, sondern auch *vorteilhaft*. *Die Wohnung liegt günstig* bedeutet *die Wohnung liegt vorteilhaft*. Anders ist *die Wohnung liegt laut*: das würde man vielleicht verstehen, ist aber ohne erklärenden Kontext sehr ungewöhnlich.

Comment: Vielen Dank für deine Antwort :)

Answer (score 4):

Ich finde den Satz nicht auffällig und es ist klar, was gemeint ist.

Außer *laut* (was an einer nahe gelegenen Straße/Kreuzung, Eisenbahnlinie oder Flugschneise liegen kann),  kommt für ein Gebäude auch *[hellhörig](https://www.dwds.de/wb/hellh%C3%B6rig)* in Frage, wenn die Wände so dünn sind, dass man den Nachbarn auch bei normaler Gesprächslautstärke hört.

Comment: Das ist interessant. Also, ich kann sagen: Das Wohnhaus oder Die Wohnung ist hellhörig.

Comment: Wobei es in einem *hellhörigen* Gebäude trotzdem *leise* sein kann und in einem nicht hellhörigen trotzdem laut, deswegen ist der Begriff meines Erachtens nicht gut zum Ausweichen geeignet, falls es um den Geräuschpegel geht...